# Setting axis breaks in ggplot with geom_errorbar, factor and coord_flip

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a graph of the CI of a variable. I need to use coord_flip and I have defined as factor some variables of the Y axis. I need to use scale_x_continuous to determine the break points on the X axis, however as I invert the axes, in reality I use scale_y_continuous. However, in both cases there is an error (Cannot use `+ .gg ()` with a single argument.) Can someone help me? How to fix this code?

```
library(ggplot2)
    
dataCLD <- data.frame(conjunto = c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'), 
                      valor = c(0.9034, 0.9130, 0.9810, 0.8753, 0.8942,
                                0.9028, 0.9495, 0.8839, 0.9754, 0.9364), 
                      erro = c(0.0078, 0.0108, 0.0045, 0.0116, 0.0098,
                               0.0106, 0.0070, 0.0152, 0.0041, 0.0098))

dataCLD$LI <- dataCLD$valor - dataCLD$erro
dataCLD$LS <- dataCLD$valor + dataCLD$erro

dataCLD$conjunto <- factor(dataCLD$conjunto, levels = dataCLD$conjunto)


ggplot(dataCLD, aes(conjunto, valor)) +
   theme_bw()+
   coord_flip()+
   geom_point() + 
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=LI, ymax=LS), size = .6, width=0.4) +
   labs(
      # title = " ",
      # subtitle = "",
      x = "",
      y = "ACC (%)") + 
   + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), breaks = seq(0, 1, by = .2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(dataCLD, aes(conjunto, valor)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), breaks = seq(0, 1, by = .2))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=LI, ymax=LS), size = .6, width=0.4) +
  theme_bw()+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(
    # title = " ",
    # subtitle = "",
    x = "",
    y = "ACC (%)")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly. Can you tell why it works if I add it before, but it doesn't work by adding it to the end code?

Comment: @AntonioMendes Hi dear, for sure, the issue I found is that you were trying to modify the axis which belongs to the factor variable, so I got error. The proper way to do that changes in ggplot is always add all aesthetic elements and scales before flipping or setting a theme for your plot. That is why now you get the expected plot. Please let me know if that was clear enough for you :)

Comment: Now it's clear. Thanks for the quick response. Have a great day.

Comment: @AntonioMendes Great! merry christmas and happy new year :)